# What is the difference between the way data in input and hidden form types are handled?

Tags: cakephp

Finally, a simple, straight-answer question :D

Background: My company has changed the way that that they handle when certain sites are used. Previously, certain sites were only delivered to on certain weeks; now, every site delivers every week. They have asked me to get rid of the weeks field on their "add new site" form. The link between week and site is still necessary for the code to work, however, so I am trying to hide the field and populate it with every single week.

Auto-populating it is simple. I just do this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Week', array('value'=>array('1','2','3','4','5')));
```

And when I debug the data getting sent from the form, I get the following, which is exactly the way I want it to work.

```
'Week' => array(
    'Week' => array(
        (int) 0 => '1',
        (int) 1 => '2',
        (int) 2 => '3',
        (int) 3 => '4',
        (int) 4 => '5'
    )
```

So the next step is simply hide that input. Easy, right? I just do one of the following two things to the form:

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('Week', array('value'=>array('1','2','3','4','5')));
```

or

```
echo $this->Form->input('Week', array('value'=>array('1','2','3','4','5'), 'type'=>'hidden'));
```

All I have done is change the type to hidden. But now, the data returned from debugging the data from the form looks like this:

```
'Week' => array(
    'Week' => '1 2 3 4 5'
```

So my question is, what is the difference in the way data is handled between a normal "input" field and a "hidden" field. Why does that difference occur, and why is it important? And for this particular issue, how do I get hidden data to behave in the same way as normal input data?

Comment: I copied both codes you provided (the normal input and the hidden one) and debug the posted result. The result is the same for both, a string with `1 2 3 4 5`. Is `Week` a multiple choice input? And what cake version are you using?

Comment: I believe we are using Cake 2.0. Week is a multiple choice input; it is handled in the form the same way that we handle putting products into a sale, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said in the comments, `Week` is a multiple choice input, so that's why the difference in value handling. If the input is something that allows multiple choice (like multiple select or checkboxes), then it's logical all values comes as an array. But the hidden type is basically a hidden text input (ok, maybe not, but I'm simplifying). Look, if you put

```
echo $this->Form->input('Week', array('type'=>'text', 'value'=>array('1','2','3','4','5')));
```

you'll get the same string as you have with the input field, so it isn't a matter of if it's hidden or not.

Now, for your case, you can add the week values as an string and change the way you handle the value on post, as a string instead of an array.

But, if by some reason that's not a possibility (too much code to change, etc), then keep the same code you have now, and hide it with css. Something like

```
echo $this->Form->input('Week', array('value'=>array('1','2','3','4','5'),
                                'div'=>array('style'=>'display:none')));
```

should do the trick (maybe a few more styles needs to be added, try with just that first).

I don't like the css solution that much, browsers can interpret css different ways and etc etc... But it fits your needs and you don't have to change anything else.

---

**EDIT**

On second though, it is possible to achieve the same array output with just hidden fields. It isn't pretty though. You have to change the name of every input to tell php it's an array, like this

```
echo $this->Form->input('Week1', array('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>1, 'name'=>'data[Week][Week][]'));
echo $this->Form->input('Week2', array('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>3, 'name'=>'data[Week][Week][]'));
echo $this->Form->input('Week3', array('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>4, 'name'=>'data[Week][Week][]'));
```

The important part is the name option for every input, see the array reference? Specially the last empty `[]`. This is actually how cakephp sends all data as an array. Have you tried to create a form without the FormHelper in cake? You wouldn't get the post data in `$this->request->data['form_name']` unless you set the input names for all your form fields.

Cake sends all post data inside the `$data` array by naming all the inputs with `<input name="data[ModelName][field_name]"` and for multiple inputs is `<input name="data[ModelName][field_name][]"` (with the empty array at the end, so it gets numerically indexed). You can see that using any html inspector on any other form created with the formhelper in cake.

I hope it's clear... I'll stick with the css solution here. The multiple hidden inputs seems messier.

Comment: Works perfectly for the case. Thank you!

So from a theoretical point of view, why does a hidden type on a multiple choice input treat is a text input instead of an array?

Comment: The reason multiple choice inputs gets send as arrays is that the name they assign is define as `<input name="multiple[]">`, that input will be interpreted as an array on post... On second though, I guess what you want is possible with hidden types too (it doesn't look pretty, thou). I'm going to update my answer with the other solution and hope you understand the difference between multiple choice input handling :)